# How do I Replace all at end of Line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, I was able to add "Double" to all variables in the list by pressing Ctrl+H using Regular Expression  Mode and replacing "\d+" with "Double".

Now I want to add a ";" to the end of each line. How would I do this?

```
Double Harness Infinity
Double Hofri Ghostforge
Double Humiliate
Double Infuse with Vitality
Double Inkling Summoning
Double Kasmina, Enigma Sage
Double Killian, Ink Duelist
Double Lorehold Apprentice
Double Lorehold Command
Double Lorehold Excavation
Double Lorehold Pledgemage
Double Maelstrom Muse
Double Magma Opus
Double Make Your Mark
Double Manifestation Sage
Double Moldering Karok
Double Mortality Spear
Double Needlethorn Drake
Double Oggyar Battle-Seer
Double Owlin Shieldmage
Double Pest Summoning
Double Practical Research
```

Comment: Find \n replace with \n;

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `$`
- Replace with: `;`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
$       # end of line
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n` and replace it with corresponding character + `;`. It depends on the system you are using but one of them should work. \r stands for return character (enter key) and \n is for newline character.